# How Should I handle this Start and End Date for each address changes in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a request to generate a report with the following data in an Oracle table: Just an example of a member.

```
MEMBER_ID  START_DATE   END_DATE    ADDRESS1          ADDRESS2   CITY         STATE    LAST_UPDATED 
12345      1/1/2019     12/31/9999  1 Test Ave        Apt 111    City         AA       3/4/2020
12345      1/1/2019     12/31/9999  2 Test Dr         Apt 222    City         AA       9/5/2019
12345      1/1/2019     12/31/9999  1 Test Ave        APT 111    City         AA       6/3/2019
12345      1/1/2019     12/31/9999  3 Test TRL                   City         AA       3/3/2019
```

I want this as my output on the report from the data above:

```
MEMBER_ID  START_DATE   END_DATE    ADDRESS1          ADDRESS2   CITY         STATE    LAST_UPDATED
12345      10/1/2019    12/31/9999  1 Test Ave        Apt 111    City         AA       3/4/2020
12345      7/1/2019     9/30/2019   2 Test Dr         Apt 222    City         AA       9/5/2019
12345      4/1/2019     6/31/2019   1 Test Ave        APT 111    City         AA       6/3/2019
12345      1/1/2019     3/31/2019   3 Test TRL                   City         AA       3/3/2019
```

Would someone be able to help with this? I tried Dense_rank but just couldn't figure a logic that would work correctly. Like if a member has another address change, i would need to pull in the latest change on the report as well.

Comment: MySQL or Oracle or SQL Server? Only tag the one you really use. And you need to explain hoe these date are related to each other. [Edit] the question and elaborate.

Comment: The END_DATE is a hard coded value in the table as every member has that END_DATE. On the report, we want to capture the START_DATE and END_DATE differently and it should be based on an update to a member's address. Whenever a member has update their address, we want to capture that in the START_DATE and END_DATE by checking in with the Last_Updated column.

Comment: Chris, can you explain a bit more how you got the dates that you show? I can't figure it out at all.

Comment: Instead of `12/31/9999` I would rather prefer `NULL`. Not all clients might be able to handle such date value.

Comment: The start dates are looking random, where they are coming from?

Comment: This is not the data that I own but the start date is whenever they started their membership.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want records to end on the last day of the month of the `last_updated` column.  Then next then begins on the next day.

This is easily handled using `lag()`:

```
select t.*,
       ( lag(last_day(last_updated)) over (partition by member_id order by last_updated) +
         interval '1' day
       ) as new_start_date,
       last_day(last_updated) as new_end_date
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a quarter start and end date of the last updated date as start and end date.

```
Select member_id,
       Trunc(last_updated,'Q') as start_date,
       case 
          when extract(month from Trunc(last_updated,'Q')) = 12
          then end_date 
          else Add_months(Trunc(last_updated,'Q'), 3) - 1 
       end as end_date,
       .....
  From your_table
```